# Reverse model admin custom URLs

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-admin

Inside my `admin.py` file I have:

```
def get_urls(self):
    urls = super(TextAdmin, self).get_urls()
    my_urls = patterns('',
        url(
            r'customfunc1',
            customfunc2,
            name='customfunc23',
        ),
    )
    return my_urls + urls
```

Which will enable the following URL:

```
http://localhost:8000/admin/text/customfunc1
```

Which will execute function `customfunc2`. My question is now how would I reference this URL through doing `reverse`?

I tried:

```
reverse("admin:text_customfunc1")
reverse("admin:text_customfunc2")
reverse("admin:text_customfunc3")
reverse("text:customfunc1")
```

But none of those work.

Answer (score 1):

You have `name='customfunc23'`, and it is in the `admin` app, so you should use:

```
reverse('admin:customfunc23')
```